# Sci-Fi short story: Side with the most advanced technology loses

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, technology, warfare

Looking for an old sci-fi short story where the side with the most advanced technology loses because of unexpected side effects of their high tech.

The story is told from the perspective of the losing side who claim that they lost because they kept inventing superior technology. For example, they create better FTL ships but after they are in service for a while they warp and become useless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost certainly Clarke's "[*Superiority*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40897)"

At the end of the story, the losing admiral doesn't want to be locked up with the head of military research because he wants to kill him for losing the war.

> "Superiority" is a science fiction short story by Arthur C. Clarke, first published in 1951. It depicts an arms race, and shows how the side which is more technologically advanced can be defeated, despite its apparent superiority, because of its own organizational flaws and its willingness to discard old technology without having fully perfected the new.
>
> <sub>[Goodreads, *Superiority*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18038608-superiority)</sub>

Comment: That's it! Thanks.